# Extract date from email using python 2.7 regex

Tags: python, regex, date

I have tried many regex code to extract the date from the emails that has this format but I couldn't:

```
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)
Sent: Thursday, November 08, 2001 10:25 AM
```

This how it looks like in all emails and I want to extract them both.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using this kind of pattern:

**Using Python3:**

```
import re
data = "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)"
final = re.findall(r"Date: (\w+), ([0-9]+) (\w+) ([0-9]+)", data)
print("{0}, {1}".format(final[0][0], " ".join(final[0][1:])))
print(" ".join(final[0][1:]))
```

**Using Python2:**

```
import re
data = "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)"
final = re.findall(r"Date: (\w+), ([0-9]+) (\w+) ([0-9]+)", data)
print "%s, %s" % (final[0][0], " ".join(final[0][1:]))
print " ".join(final[0][1:])
```

**Output:**

```
Tue, 13 Nov 2001
13 Nov 2001
```

**Edit:**

A quick answer to the new update of your question, you can do something like this:

```
import re 

email = '''Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)
Sent: Thursday, November 08, 2001 10:25 AM'''
data = email.split("\n")

pattern = r"(\w+: \w+, [0-9]+ \w+ [0-9]+)|(\w+: \w+, \w+ [0-9]+, [0-9]+)"

final = []
for k in data:
    final += re.findall(pattern, k)

final = [j.split(":") for k in final for j in k if j != '']
# Python3 
print(final)
# Python2
# print final
```

Output:

```
[['Date', ' Tue, 13 Nov 2001'], ['Sent', ' Thursday, November 08, 2001']]
```

Comment: also, I want to extract this date in the body of the email
Sent: Thursday, November 08, 2001 10:25 AM
how can I extract them both?

Comment: Please edit your question and post an example of your email data and i'll edit my answer to fill your needs.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Look now and return your feedbacks if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

my_email = 'Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)'

match = re.search(r': (\w{3,3}, \d{2,2} \w{3,3} \d{4,4})', my_email)
print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I am not regex expert but here is a solution, you can write some tests for that

```
d = "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)"
dates = [re.search('(\d+ \w+ \d+)',date).groups()[0] for date in re.search('(Date: \w+, \d+ \w+ \d+)', d).groups()]
```

> ['13 Nov 2001']

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you can use `split()` if only extract the same string model:

```
email_date = "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2001 08:41:49 -0800 (PST)"
email_date = '%s %s %s %s' % (tuple(email_date.split(' ')[1:5]))
```

Output:

```
Tue, 13 Nov 2001
```